# What is the difference between passing the statement Chem.MolFromSmiles directly or via a variable?

Tags: python, rdkit

If I do not store the `rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol` object in a variable but pass the statement `Chem.MolFromSmiles("<your-smile>")` directly into another function it gives a different result than storing it in a variable before!

Why is that?

```
>>> from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
>>> from rdkit import Chem



>>> # direct approach
>>> print(Descriptors.TPSA(Chem.MolFromSmiles('OC(=O)P(=O)(O)O')))
94.83
>>> print(Descriptors.TPSA(Chem.MolFromSmiles('OC(=O)P(=O)(O)O'), includeSandP=True))
104.64000000000001



>>> # mol as variable approach
>>> mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('OC(=O)P(=O)(O)O')
>>> print(Descriptors.TPSA(mol))
94.83
>>> print(Descriptors.TPSA(mol, includeSandP=True))
94.83
```

In my mind the last `print`statement should also give a result of ~104.64

This links you to the example that I am using: [TPSA](https://rdkit.org/docs/RDKit_Book.html?highlight=tpsa#implementation-of-the-tpsa-descriptor)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but my guess is that `TPSA()` is caching its results in the `Mol` object you pass to it.  In your first approach, you're calling it on two separate `Mol`s; in the second approach, you're calling it on the same `Mol` twice, just with a different optional parameter the second time.  (If this is the case, then it's a bug in the library - the `includeSandP` value should be considered in the cache.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the party but @jasonharper is correct the TPSA value is cached in the molecule object:

```py
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
from rdkit import Chem

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('OC(=O)P(=O)(O)O')
tpsa = Descriptors.TPSA(mol)

# Show cached property
mol.GetPropsAsDict(includeComputed=True, includePrivate=True)

Out:

{'__computedProps': <rdkit.rdBase._vectNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE at 0x7fd38aa93740>,
 'numArom': 0,
 '_StereochemDone': 1,
 '_tpsaAtomContribs': <rdkit.rdBase._vectd at 0x7fd38aa932e0>,
 '_tpsa': 94.83}
```

If you delete the two properties `_tpsa` and `_tpsaAtomContribs` you should get the result you are expecting:

```py
mol.ClearProp("_tpsa")
mol.ClearProp("_tpsaAtomContribs")

tpsa_sandp = Descriptors.TPSA(mol, includeSandP=True)
assert tpsa != tpsa_sandp
```

The best way though is to simply ignore the cache using `force=True`

```py
assert Descriptors.TPSA(mol, force=True) != tpsa_sandp
```

Comment: Thanks! If you are interested read [here](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/discussions/5925) the answer of the official maintainer of rdkit.

Comment: Nice to know that they consider this to be a bug!